# Should story-identification requests that turn out to be about the same story be marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, story-identification, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6642/19561) and [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6060/19561) are about the same book, *Profession* by Asimov, as evidenced by the accepted answers. There is [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/30918/19561) that's probably about the same book as well, but it has no accepted answer, so we can't say for sure.

Should we mark one question as a duplicate of the other? And should we do this in all cases of duplicate *accepted* answers to [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions?

Please vote on my answer to voice your opinion, or leave another answer, of course.

Comment: Closing this question as a duplicate (yes, how meta, I know) since the discussion was reopened over a year later and a clear policy established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first two questions are duplicates of each other, since they're asking for the same book.

If [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions have duplicate (accepted!) answers, that means they are duplicate questions and so they should be marked as such.

Comment: If it's accepted (or very clearly the same book) then yes. If it's not accepted (or there's a possibility they're referring to two different books then no.

Comment: @Richard Sadly, "very clearly the same" is subjective.